# Chunking lists lua 5.1.5

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am using Lua 5.1.5 and trying to cut tables into chunks(?). I am trying to break apart a table into something like this:

```lua
{{a, b, c ,d}, {e, f, g, h}, ...}
```

Anyone got an idea on how to do that?

Edit: Forgot Lua had tables instead of lists so replaced those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt this code:

```
t={}
n=34
local unpack = unpack or table.unpack
for i=1,n do t[i]=i end
for i=1,#t,4 do
    print(i,unpack(t,i,i+3))
end
```

The key point is the function [unpack](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack), which is a global function in Lua 5.1 but resides in `table` in Lua 5.2+.

Comment: Note that this may yield trailing `nil`s if the length of the table is not divisible by 4.

Comment: @LMD, sure, but that won’t make a different when creating the smaller tables

Comment: @lhf I had a question about the code, as I see, some numbers duplicate. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @Joohane, there no duplicates; the code prints `i` along with the subtable.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't trailing `nil`, based on @lhf anser

```lua
-- set up unpack to be compatible with old and new versions of lua
local unpack = unpack or table.unpack

-- create a table of {1: 1, 2: 2, ...}
t = {}
n = 34
for i=1,n do t[i]=i end

-- print out chunks
chunk_size = 4
for i=1,#t,chunk_size do
    print(unpack(t, i, math.min(#t, i + chunk_size - 1)))
end
```

Output

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24
25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32
33  34
```